# Push state updates directly to conditionally rendered React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm building a React app and have a tab section, where clicking on a tab will render a specific component.

First, my parent component:

```js
class Interface extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.chooseTab = this.chooseTab.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            current: 'inventory',
            inventory: [],
            skills: [],
            friends: [],
            notifications: {}
        };
    }

    chooseTab(tabID) {
      this.setState({ current: tabID });

    chooseComponent(tabID) {
        if (tabID === 'skills') return Skills;
        else if (tabID === 'inventory') return Inventory;
        else if (tabID === 'friends') return FriendsList;
    }

    render() {
        const tabID = this.state.current;
        const CustomComponent = this.chooseComponent(tabID);
        return (
            <div className='column' id='interface'>
              <div className='row' id='tabs'>
                <ActiveTab
                  current={this.state.current}
                  tabID='skills'
                  chooseTab={this.chooseTab}
                />
                <ActiveTab
                  current={this.state.current}
                  tabID='inventory'
                  chooseTab={this.chooseTab}
                />
                <ActiveTab
                  current={this.state.current}
                  tabID='friends'
                  chooseTab={this.chooseTab}
                />
              </div>
              <TabBody>
                <CustomComponent
                  data={this.state[tabID]}
                  notifications={this.state.notifications}
                />
              </TabBody>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Which renders three ActiveTab's and one TabBody:

```html
const ActiveTab = (props) => {
    const isActive = props.tabID === props.current ? 'active' : 'inactive';
    return (
      <button
        className={`active-tab ${isActive}`}
        onClick={() => props.chooseTab(props.tabID)}
      >{props.tabID}
      </button>
    );
};

const TabBody = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className='tab-body'>
          {props.children}
        </div>
    );
};
```

This works fine, and it's clearly an [intended way](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html) of handling this issue. However, I'd like to be able to move the `notifications` state object into my `FriendsList` component (since it's unique to friends) and also trigger a `setState` in it from another component even if `FriendsList` is not the component currently rendered by the TabBody (i.e., unmounted).

I'm currently triggering remote state changes using a globally available `actions` closure where a specific action and `setState` is defined in the `ComponentWillMount()` lifecycle method of the target element, and it's executed from whatever component is activating the remote state change. I've left those out of `Interface` for brevity.

How would you handle this? Is my only option to leave `notifications` in `Interface`, define actions there, and let React handle passing props down? Or is there a way to build my tab components and conditional rendering so I can trigger state changes from a separate component to a non-displayed component in one of the tabs, i.e move `notifications` and its corresponding action to `FriendsList`?

Comment: Have you looked into using [redux](http://redux.js.org/)?

Comment: I have, and it's certainly a more elegant solution than my current one, but unfortunately the rest of the team is not convinced as of now. Looking for another solution in the meantime.

Comment: In that case: Is my only option to leave notifications in Interface, define actions there, and let React handle passing props down? Yes that is your only option. You can either use redux/mobx/some other state management library, or you will need to keep state high in the component hierarchy and pass down props, as well as functions to update the state.

Comment: I figured as much, though I'll keep looking into it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I've passed through a problem similar than yours weeks ago, if you are not decided to adopts some state manager like Redux, MobX or even Flux I think you should pass props down to their child's.